# Entity class has no field or association named like in my DB

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to create an request that recovers a number according to e.rules_id, e.status_id

```
public function findStat() 
{
 $types = $this->em
        ->getRepository('EthanRestBundle:EthanRules')
        ->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->select('e.rules_id, e.status_id, COUNT(*)')
        ->groupBy('e.rules_id, e.status_id')
        ->orderBy('rules_id');

    $types = $types->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();

    return $types;

}
```

The error message:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 9 near 'rules_id, e.status_id,': Error: Class Ethan\RestBundle\Entity\EthanRules has no field or association named rules_id"

I develop on Symfony 2 with FosrestBundle to create a REST Application

Comment: show your EnthanRules entity field names, probably you have different names in entity and in database. For example if in entity you have _public $rulesId_ you change your code like _e.rulesId_ instead of e.rules_id

Comment: the problem is not in count(*) but in the error. please update your title

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine by default names all fields with camelCase in the entity classes but with_underscores in the Database.

You need to change your `rules_id` and `status_id` to `rules` and `status` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace Ethan\RestBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * EthanRules
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ethan_rules")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class EthanRules
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="customer_key", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $customerKey;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="subscription_key", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $subscriptionKey;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="pole", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $pole;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="link_number", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $linkNumber;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_rdv", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $dateRdv;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @var \Rules
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Rules")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="rules_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $rules;

    /**
     * @var \Status
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Status")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="status_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $status;



    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
        $this->createdAt->setTimestamp(time());
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set customerKey
     *
     * @param string $customerKey
     * @return EthanRules
     */
    public function setCustomerKey($customerKey)
    {
        $this->customerKey = $customerKey;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get customerKey
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCustomerKey()
    {
        return $this->customerKey;
    }

    /**
     * Set subscriptionKey
     *
     * @param string $subscriptionKey
     * @return EthanRules
     */
    public function setSubscriptionKey($subscriptionKey)
    {
        $this->subscriptionKey = $subscriptionKey;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get subscriptionKey
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSubscriptionKey()
    {
        return $this->subscriptionKey;
    }

    /**
     * Set pole
     *
     * @param string $pole
     * @return EthanRules
     */
    public function setPole($pole)
    {
        $this->pole = $pole;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get pole
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPole()
    {
        return $this->pole;
    }

    /**
     * Set linkNumber
     *
     * @param string $linkNumber
     * @return EthanRules
     */
    public function setLinkNumber($linkNumber)
    {
        $this->linkNumber = $linkNumber;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get linkNumber
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLinkNumber()
    {
        return $this->linkNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param string $user
     * @return EthanRules
     */
    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateRdv
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateRdv
     * @return EthanRules
     */
    public function setDateRdv($dateRdv)
    {
        $this->dateRdv = $dateRdv;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateRdv
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDateRdv()
    {
        return $this->dateRdv;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     * @return EthanRules
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set updatedAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
     * @return EthanRules
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set rules
     *
     * @param \Ethan\RestBundle\Entity\Rules $rules
     * @return EthanRules
     */
    public function setRules(\Ethan\RestBundle\Entity\Rules $rules = null)
    {
        $this->rules = $rules;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get rules
     *
     * @return \Ethan\RestBundle\Entity\Rules 
     */
    public function getRules()
    {
        return $this->rules;
    }

    /**
     * Set status
     *
     * @param \Ethan\RestBundle\Entity\Status $status
     * @return EthanRules
     */
    public function setStatus(\Ethan\RestBundle\Entity\Status $status = null)
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get status
     *
     * @return \Ethan\RestBundle\Entity\Status 
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not defined a property `$rules_id` Doctrine can not select one. Instead join both entities and select their ids:

```
$types = $this->em
    ->getRepository('EthanRestBundle:EthanRules')
    ->createQueryBuilder('e')
    ->select('r.id AS rule_id, s.id AS status_id, COUNT(DISTINCT e.id)')
    ->leftJoin('e.rules', 'r')
    ->leftJoin('e.status', 's')
    ->groupBy('r.id, s.id')
    ->orderBy('r.id');
```

BUT: you use `getSingleScalarResult()` which will not work with multiple result rows!
Propably `getArrayResult()` will be best choice for you, since it looks like you don't want to work with objects.

Comment: @Ali did this work for you? If not tell me whats the problem. Otherwise you could accept this answer as the correct one